# Having a module singleton extending a class

Tags: ruby, eigenclass

I have a singleton in my application that gets reused across applications. I want that singleton to get some default methods from my class, but also be able to customize the module/eigenclass. Most of all, I don't want to call up `instance` on every call the the utility singleton.

Here's an example. Let's say my default class is `Universe::Earth`. Then I want an `Earth` module in my application that "extends" that class.

```
module Universe
  class Earth
    def self.grow!
      @grown = true
    end
  end
end

module Earth
  class < Universe::Earth << self; end

  grow!
end
```

When that's run, `grow!` is a `NoMethodError`.

Tried those approaches:

```
Class.new(Goodluck::Contest) << self
class < Universe::Earth << self; end
extend Universe::Earth
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Not quite. I'm trying to create a DSL for it. So calling `Earth` every time would be a pain.

Comment: Jonathan, sorry for the delay in modifying my answer. Let me know if it still doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

```
module Universe
  class Earth
    def self.grow!
      @grown = true
    end
  end
end

module Earth
  Universe::Earth.class_eval do
    define_method(:instance_howdy) do
      puts "instance_howdy!"
    end
  end
  def (Universe::Earth).class_howdy
    puts "class_howdy!"
  end
end

Universe::Earth.methods(false)          #=> [:grow!, :class_howdy]
Universe::Earth.instance_methods(false) #=> [:instance_howdy]
Universe::Earth.new.instance_howdy      #=> instance_howdy!
Universe::Earth.class_howdy             #=> class_howdy!
```

**[Edit:** If you just want to set `@grown => true`, and retrieve it's value, you merely need:

```
module Earth
  Universe::Earth.grow! #=> true
end
```

Verify:

```
Universe::Earth.instance_variable_get("@grown") #=> true
```

If you wish to also add an accessor for the class instance variable, you could do this:

```
def add_class_accessor(c, accessor, var)  
  c.singleton_class.class_eval("#{accessor} :#{var}")
end

Universe::Earth.methods(false)
  #=> [:grow!]

module Earth
  Universe::Earth.grow! #=> true
  add_class_accessor(Universe::Earth, "attr_accessor", "grown")
end

Universe::Earth.methods(false)
  #=> [:grow!, :grown, :grown=]

Universe::Earth.grown
  #=> true
Universe::Earth.grown = "cat"
  #=> "cat"
Universe::Earth.grown
  #=> "cat"
```

[Object#singleton_class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) was added in Ruby 1.9.2. For earlier versions you could do this:

```
def add_class_accessor(c, accessor, var)
  eigenclass = class << c; self; end
  eigenclass.class_eval("#{accessor} :#{var}")
end
```

You might consider putting `add_class_accessor` in a module to be included as needed.  Other methods you might add to the same module might be:

```
add_instance_method(klass, method, &block)
add_class_method(klass, method, &block)
add_instance_accessor(klass, accessor, var)
```

**:tidE**

Comment: I'm trying to make `Earth.grow!; Earth.grown == true` (assume attr reader)